# Access printer in VLAN1 from VLAN2

Tags: cisco, vlan

I have a network printer (Brother MFC-L8690CDW) connected to Cisco RV340W (with latest firmware) on VLAN1.

I have installed driver and it works as usual no issues there.

Now we have created VLAN2.

My Question: Is it possible to let devices on VLAN2 (see, access, print) on printer on VLAN1? Bear on me it is new area I am touching. I have of course looked at static routing. But at the same time a bit unsure if it is possible at all and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of a VLAN as a virtual switch. Devices on different VLANs (virtual switches) share no common (data link layer) network, so they cannot communicate directly.

A router connects different networks with each other, so attaching a router in between both VLANs and configuring the routing enables nodes to talk to each other across those VLANs.

Configuring the routing means that each VLAN needs to use its own IP subnet. All nodes need to use their VLAN's router interface as gateway to the other VLAN(s). In the simplest case that router interface is just the default gateway.

Since the RV340W is a router and likely your nodes' default gateway as well, all you need to do is enable inter-VLAN routing and possibly set up a rule permitting the traffic.

Answer (score 1):

By default, different VLANs won't communicate with each other. You can make them communicate by inter-VLAN routing. For this requirement, you require one router and one switch. Instead of this, you can create layer 2 same vlans in switch and allocate both printers to the same vlan.

In the switch, configure both ports on vlan 1 so that both printers can talk..

option 1 : you can use router and switch and configure router on -stick

option 2 : you can use layer2 switch and create layer2 vlan2 and connect both printer to same vlan .

option 3 : in single router your can use two different network and connect two printers to establish connectivity between them . please fallow below diagram for option 3

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering, just to make it clear, it is only one printer and 2 vlans, so vlan2 need access to printer on vlan1 and intervlan routing is enabled already. Or did I misunderstood you? thanks

Comment: thank you for your answer, I found the other answer fitting best.